# Cython: why "duplicate symbol"?

Tags: c++, cython

I'm new to Cython, so please forgive me if this is a noob question. I'm trying to modify the [primes example](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html#primes) into a pure c++ (.h/.cpp) implementation which then is wrapped by a .pyx file.

**primes.h:**

```
#include <list>

std::list<int> primes2_c(int maxn);
```

**primes.cpp**:

```
#include "primes.h"

#include <list>

std::list<int> primes2_c(int maxn) {
    int n;
    std::list<int> ret;
    n = 2;
    while (n < maxn) {
        auto it = ret.begin();
        for (; it != ret.end() && n % *it != 0; it++);
        if (it == ret.end()) {
            ret.push_back(n);
        }
        n++;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**primes.pyx**:

```
cdef extern from "primes.h":
    list[int] primes2_c(int)

def primes2(kmax):
    ret = primes2_c(kmax)
    return ret
```

**primes.setup**:

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    name='primes',
    ext_modules=cythonize(Extension(
        'primes',
        ['primes.pyx', 'primes.cpp'],
        language='c++',
        extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
        extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"],
    ))
)
```

Then I run the compilation and see this error:

```
[cython (master)]$ python primes.setup build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
building 'primes' extension
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/.../venv/cython/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c primes.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/primes.o -std=c++11
/usr/bin/clang -fno-strict-aliasing -Wsign-compare -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -I/Users/.../venv/cython/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m -c primes.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/primes.o -std=c++11
/usr/bin/clang++ -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/primes.o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/primes.o -o /Users/.../cython/primes.cpython-35m-darwin.so -std=c++11
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
duplicate symbol __Z9primes2_ci in:
    build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-3.5/primes.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang++' failed with exit status 1
[cython (master)]$
```

My understanding is that **primes.pyx** only reads the API of `primes2_c()` but not the implementation. So the only implementation provided for the same function should be from the reference to **primes.cpp** in **primes.setup**.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Cython.build`, but from the build log you can see that it's compiling `primes.o` from `primes.cpp` *twice*, and then when it tries to build the `.so` it's trying to link in `primes.o` twice.

Comment: Your observation is correct. I also observed that. My OP was trying to ask "why implementation in primes.cpp is linked twice".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you rename `primes.cpp` to e.g. `primesc.cpp`?  I think `primes.pyx` is compiled to `primes.cpp` by Cython as part of the build, so there's a filename clash.

Comment: Indeed, as you said, naming both `.cpp` and `.pyx` using the same primary filename was the problem. However, it's unexpected for me, and I'd like to think it's an issue on Cython side, since it generates a build folder anyways, and I'd expect any intermediate file to be placed into the build folder. But anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: I further discovered that the `.pyx` file should have the same name as the package name, since renaming it into something like `wrapper.pyx` will lead to `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_prime)`. The hardcoded naming rules here are quite easy to miss for newbies IMHO.